# How to record on two cameras simultaneously in Android?

Tags: android, video, camera

Is it possible to record two videos simultaneously using the front and back camera in Android.

In an article I read they mention it requires a dual processor device.

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions/guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to make it a little clearer? Your question title makes it sound like you want to *play* two videos at once, whereas your question body makes it seem as though you want to *record* two videos at once. Which is it? Or is it both?

Comment: @Phil : thanks for reply...yes it's actually for both...but once i want to sure to play two video simultaneously, so then can approach for record two video simultaneously.pls let me know ur feedback/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But only on certain phones.

I have found the HTC One m8, the Oneplus One and the Mototola Nexus 6 capable of this. For the rest I don't know, yet. I have found no other way to find if they do or don't support this than through testing with an app and to see if it crashes or not.

You have to create a seperate camera object for the front and the rear, though (just iterate through the array of available camera's).

-edit-
It seems to be something I can at least confirm works for (certain? Maybe not all) phone which have the Snapdragon 801 chipset and upwards.

Comment: Great thanks MacD..after this much time still it worth to work on it.